# Encoding textfield

Tags: php, text, encoding, textfield

I have problem with a text field. When I write a special character like this:

```
aaaaa éééé @@@@
```

The text field returns:

```
<div>aaaaa &eacute;&eacute;&eacute;&eacute; @@@@</div>
```

Can you help me?

My code:

```
                    <div>
                    <label for="******"><span style="float: right;"><?php *******;?></span></label>
                    <fieldset>
                        <textarea id="*****" name="*****" data-dojo-type="dojox/****/TextArea"
                            style="width:100%;" maxLength="400" data-dojo-props="value:''" ></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your examples are looking equal here. Both look like `aaaaa éééé @@@@` So what is the issue?

Comment: Oh i'm so sorry , i have edit the post

Comment: `print html_entity_decode ('aaaaa &eacute;&eacute;&eacute;&eacute; @@@@',ENT_HTML5);` if on php >= 5.4.0,  but you have to learn about encoing at all, there a still bottlenecks and tricks to now. read the dublicates.

Comment: i try your solution but i have again <div>aaa ééé @@@</div> !  I use html_entity_decode on my variable . Without html_entity_decode i have "<div>aaa &eacute;&eacute;&eacute; @@@</div>" and with your solution  i have <div>aaa ééé @@@</div>

Comment: And did you see the difference in the HTML code, that one version has `&eacute;` and the other has an real char `é` in the html-content (big difference!!!!).  By the way, what do you want do archive here?

Comment: yes of course. But i want "aaa ééé @@@" without the <div> !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133821/discussion-between-krowry-and-justonundermillions).

Comment: Of course ;-)  You never talked about the `<div>`, it was about `encoding & special character`, but if that is all use `strip_tags()`

Comment: Nope, no disco,  its an easy question if right asked. Try my last comment.

Comment: Oh yes that's working ! thanks you !